# display one word in a <span> as another word using css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, abbreviation

So, the word is **International** for example.

I would like to do something like this for mobile phones for example:

```
<span class="word-international">International</span>
```

and then style as follows for mobile phone:

```
.word-international{
    content:"Int'l";
}
```

for obvious space reasons (and SEO reasons).  This does not work, but I seem to remember there is some way to do this, I just cannot recall the specific HTML tag or attribute within the tag, something like <abbr> - thanks!

Comment: You can use <abbr> but I don't think it is exactly what you're looking for. It would be something like this: `<abbr title="International">Int'l</abbr>`

Comment: try leaving the span empty... use a before with the content:"international", which u can change it on mobile to content:"Int'l".

Answer (score 0):

Css content property only works on :before, :after pseudo elements, it doesn't work on the direct elements. So you could do something like this

HTML

```
<span class="test">
    <span>Hello</span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .test span {
      display:none;
  }
  .test:after {
    content: "Test";
  }
}
```

If you are using a mobile first approach, then change the css accordingly, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to physically change the content in the same element I can think of one way to do this. You have to create a pseudoelement for mobile devices

```
@media (max-width:720px) {
   .word-international::before {
       content:"Int'l";
       font-size:12px;
    }
   .word-international {
       font-size:0px; //hide text only. if you hide whole element the pseudoelement won't be visible as well.
    }
}
```

But I'd suggest using some js to change the content of element or even better have two elements with classes `mobile` and `desktop` and use media queries to show/hide them

```
@media (max-width:720px) {
   .word-international.mobile {
       display: block;
    }
    .word-international.desktop {
       display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:721px) {
   .word-international.desktop {
       display: block;
    }
    .word-international.mobile {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

This is the way it's usually done.

Comment: there are drawbacks to each method (both are ingenious BTW).  The first one forces the font to be something that doesn't scale to the surrounding font-size, and the second forces me to write inline text that is not `true t 1 yes y` to real speech (I did an example in this sentence).

Comment: Why exactly are you worried about conversion to real speech? If it's about accessibility for the blind through screen readers you could introduce another media query for that (`@media speech`) and hide the elements you don't want read there. Here's a list off other media-types you might find helpful - [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types).